# Contour integral of square root on its Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, riemann-surfaces

Consider a branch of the square root function $f(z)=z^{1/2}, z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $Im \thinspace {f(z)}>=0$, i.e. 
                            $f(re^{i\phi}):=\sqrt{r}e^{i(\phi \thinspace mod  \thinspace 2\pi)/2}.$ 
The function is not holomorphic at the origin and has a discontinuity on the non-negative real axis. Consequently, the contour integral of the function along the unit circle doesn't vanish. 
If we extend the function to it's Riemann surface then we'll get a single-valued continuous function, (informally $F(re^{i\phi})=\sqrt{r}e^{i\phi/2}$). 
The contour integral along the "double unit circle" $z(\phi)=e^{i\phi}, \phi\in{[0,4\pi]}$ on the Riemann surface now vanishes.
I suspect this will be true for any other closed curve on the Riemann surface.
Is there a way to understand this in context of the residue theorem, suitably generalized to Riemann surfaces? Is it correct to say that the origin has now become an isolated (essential) singularity whose residue is zero and hence the integral of the function along any closed curve on the Riemann surface must always vanish?

Comment: Its Riemann surface is $X =\{(z,z^{1/2}), z \in \Bbb{C}^*\}$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}^*$ and the image of $z^{1/2}$ is $z$ having a removable singularity at $z=0$. The function field of $X$ becomes the field of meromorphic functions on $\Bbb{C}^*$. It is their derivatives having vanishing "residue" $\int_{|z|=r}  dF = 0$ corresponding to $\int_{|z^{1/2}| = r^{1/2} \in X} dF(z^{1/2}) = 0$ on $X$. Note $F$ can have infinitely many poles around $z=0$ (so infinitely many different $r$) to disallow that you need to add the $z=0$  point to obtain $\Bbb{C}$ instead of $\Bbb{C}^*$.

Comment: Why is the integral $\int_{|z^{1/2}|=r^{1/2}∈X} dF(z^{1/2})=0$ ? Is $dF(z^{1/2})$ a closed form on the Riemann surface?

Comment: $F(z)$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb{C}^*$ iff $f = F(z^{1/2})$ is meromorphic on $X$ and $df$ is exact holomorphic one-form on $X$ minus the poles of $f$.  Of course $z^{1/2}$ is not the principal branch of the squareroot, it is the multivalued one corresponding to the charts of $X$.

Comment: Concretely $\int_{|z^{1/2}|=r^{1/2}∈X} dF(z^{1/2}) = \int_0^{4\pi} dF(r^{1/2} e^{it/2}) =F( r^{1/2} e^{it/2})|_0^{4\pi}$